# "No upgrade items found" when running docker-compose exec backend aerich upgrade

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am building a FASTAPI/vuejs app and I am using Docker to spin up containers for it all. I am following along with this tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/developing-a-single-page-app-with-fastapi-and-vuejs/, and its been great until i get to the modelss/migrations portion.

here is the tree of my backend folder:

```
services/backend
├── Dockerfile
├── migrations
│   └── models
│       ├── 9_20230615065628_None.py
│       └── __pycache__
│           └── 9_20230615065628_None.cpython-311.pyc
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── main.cpython-311.pyc
    ├── auth
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── jwthandler.cpython-311.pyc
    │   │   └── users.cpython-311.pyc
    │   ├── jwthandler.py
    │   └── users.py
    ├── crud
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── notes.cpython-311.pyc
    │   │   └── users.cpython-311.pyc
    │   ├── notes.py
    │   └── users.py
    ├── database
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── config.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── config.cpython-311.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-311.pyc
    │   │   └── register.cpython-311.pyc
    │   ├── config.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   └── register.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── routes
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── notes.cpython-311.pyc
    │   │   └── users.cpython-311.pyc
    │   ├── notes.py
    │   └── users.py
    └── schemas
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── notes.cpython-311.pyc
        │   ├── token.cpython-311.pyc
        │   └── users.cpython-311.pyc
        ├── notes.py
        ├── token.py
        └── users.py
```

whenever i go to follow this sequence of commands:

docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose exec backend aerich init -t src.database.config.TORTOISE_ORM
docker-compose exec backend aerich init-db
docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose exec backend aerich migrate
docker-compose exec backend aerich upgrade

it builds all the migrations, initializes everything, but on the upgrade, it keeps saying that there are "No upgrade items found"

This is the migration file:

```
from tortoise import BaseDBAsyncClient


async def upgrade(db: BaseDBAsyncClient) -> str:
    return """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "username" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "full_name" VARCHAR(50),
    "password" VARCHAR(128),
    "created_at" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "modified_at" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "notes" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    "content" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "priority" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "modified_at" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "author_id" INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "users" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "aerich" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "version" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "app" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "content" JSONB NOT NULL
);"""


async def downgrade(db: BaseDBAsyncClient) -> str:
    return """
        """
```

So I guess it thinks it has already sent these to the database, but these tables are not in my table. The password and table name are all correct.

Let me know if anyone can help!